# How to cluster events in a domino effect in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's see if any of you can come with a solution, because I have not been able of finding any so far:

I have this table:

```
Hour    w1  w2  w3  w4  w5
8:05    1   0   0   0   0
8:10    1   0   0   0   0
8:15    0   1   0   0   1
8:20    0   1   0   1   1
8:25    0   0   1   1   1
8:30    0   0   1   1   1
8:35    0   1   1   1   0
8:40    1   1   1   1   0
8:45    0   0   1   0   1
```

What I want is to identify clusters as events. One event is created if it is formed at any point. It propagates if the previous value is a 1 or the variable next to the right has a one in the previous row.

Following the last table, the events are be located like this:

```
Hour      w1          w2          w3        w4       w5
8:05    EVENT 1       0           0         0        0
8:10    EVENT 1       0           0         0        0
8:15      0         EVENT 2       0         0       EVENT 3
8:20      0         EVENT 2       0       EVENT 3   EVENT 3
8:25      0           0         EVENT 3   EVENT 3   EVENT 3
8:30      0           0         EVENT 3   EVENT 3   EVENT 3
8:35      0         EVENT 3     EVENT 3   EVENT 3    0
8:40    EVENT 3     EVENT 3     EVENT 3   EVENT 3    0
8:45      0           0         EVENT 3     0       EVENT 4
```

Thank you! Let me know if there are any questions about the problem.

PS:
The first table can be seen 'vertically' instead of horizontally in the following way:

```
Hour    Position    Value
8:05      w1          1
8:05      w2          0
8:05      w3          0
8:05      w4          0
8:05      w5          0
8:10      w1          1
8:10      w2          0
...       ...         ...
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would describe this as a hard problem -- and interesting.  I'm pretty sure that the most general solution requires recursive CTEs.  However, that can be really cumbersome and expensive -- it is basically an iterative process.

With a few assumptions, this can be solved using merely complicated queries rather than recursive CTEs.  The primary assumption is that no vertical string of adjacent "1"s is "interrupted" by a new group from the right.

The following code encodes the clusters, using strings and not numbers.  It does not produce exactly the output you want, but it does identify the clusters:

```
with t as (
      select *
      from (values ('8:05', 1,   0,   0,  0,   0),
                   ('8:10', 1,   0,   0,   0,   0),
                   ('8:15', 0,   1,   0,   0,   1),
                   ('8:20', 0,   1,   0,   1,   1),
                   ('8:25', 0,   0,   1,   1,   1),
                   ('8:30', 0,   0,   1,   1,   1),
                   ('8:35', 0,   1,   1,   1,   0),
                   ('8:40', 1,   1,   1,   1,   0),
                   ('8:45', 0,   0,   1,   0,   1)
           ) v(hour, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5) 
     ),
     t5 as (
      select t.*,
             (case when w1 = 1 then 'w1_' || sum(case when w1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by hour) end) as w1_grp,
             (case when w2 = 1 then 'w2_' || sum(case when w2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by hour) end) as w2_grp,
             (case when w3 = 1 then 'w3_' || sum(case when w3 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by hour) end) as w3_grp,
             (case when w4 = 1 then 'w4_' || sum(case when w4 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by hour) end) as w4_grp,
             (case when w5 = 1 then 'w5_' || sum(case when w5 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by hour) end) as w5_grp_final
      from t
     ),
     t4 as (
      select t5.*,
             (case when w4 = 1 then greatest(w4_grp, max(prev_w5_grp_final) over (partition by w4_grp)) end) as w4_grp_final
      from (select t5.*, lag(w5_grp_final) over (order by hour) as prev_w5_grp_final
            from t5
           ) t5
     ),
     t3 as (
      select t4.*,
             (case when w3 = 1 then greatest(w3_grp, max(prev_w4_grp_final) over (partition by w3_grp)) end) as w3_grp_final
      from (select t4.*, lag(w4_grp_final) over (order by hour) as prev_w4_grp_final
            from t4
           ) t4
     ),
     t2 as (
      select t3.*,
             (case when w2 = 1 then greatest(w2_grp, max(prev_w3_grp_final) over (partition by w2_grp)) end) as w2_grp_final
      from (select t3.*, lag(w3_grp_final) over (order by hour) as prev_w3_grp_final
            from t3
           ) t3
     ),
     t1 as (
      select t2.*,
             (case when w1 = 1 then greatest(w1_grp, max(prev_w2_grp_final) over (partition by w1_grp)) end) as w1_grp_final
      from (select t2.*, lag(w2_grp_final) over (order by hour) as prev_w2_grp_final
            from t2
           ) t2
     )
select hour, w1_grp_final, w2_grp_final, w3_grp_final, w4_grp_final, w5_grp_final
from t1
order by hour asc;
```

The basic idea is simple.  It identifies the clusters in the right-most column and then uses the rules to propagate these leftwards, one column at a time.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4e3878fc90630e3f6f9554cc9f2135b8) is a db<>fiddle.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75faa82cac5bb81dbb57160e645ffe28) is a db<>fiddle for SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is useful. I am trying to compile it in SQL server to see if I can identify more cluster because the database I put here is just an example. The one I work with is larger

Comment: @zhivab . . .That is a relatively simple transformation.  It would have been simpler if you had just tagged the question correctly in the first place.  Note:  I also made a very small change in one of the CTEs due a typo.

Comment: Do you know why it says incorrect syntax near ( in the with? I tried to write a semicolon ; before the with but it would not work. Am I missing something in the CTE?

Comment: @zhivab . . . I'm not sure what you are referring to.  The code works in db<>fiddle.

Comment: Do you think there is any way of knowing how many times it has propagated? For instance, in the example EVENT3 propagates 5 times since it goes from w5 to w1

Comment: My best advise would be to unpivot the data and use a `count(distinct)`.  You can ask another question, if you need details.